# How to execute date range query on date index - SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene, date-range, faceted-search

What is the correct way to run the range queries on SOLR `date` index field. Below is the snapshot from `schema.xml` file for the field definition:

```
<dynamicField name="ds_*"  type="pdate"   indexed="true"  stored="false" multiValued="false" docValues="true"/>
```

Context: The SOLR document contains a date element and value as `"ds_clip_date":"2020-10-14T12:00:00Z"`.
Requirement is to allow user to fetch documents from this month/last 30 days/last 90 days/this year.

I tried building below from SOLR query dashboard - but this gives me all the documents without respecting the range:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore/select?facet.field=ds_clip_date&facet.query=facet.range%3Dds_clip_date%26f.ds_clip_date.facet.range.start%3D2020-11-17&facet=on&fl=ds_clip_date&q=*%3A*&rows=200&start=0
```

and I get the below summary:

```
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{
      "facet.range=ds_clip_date&f.ds_clip_date.facet.range.start=2020-11-17":0},
    "facet_fields":{
      "ds_clip_date":[
        "2020-12-15T12:00:00Z",20,
        "2020-12-16T12:00:00Z",14,
        "2020-09-25T12:00:00Z",1,
        "2020-10-14T12:00:00Z",1,
        "2020-10-20T12:00:00Z",1,
        "2020-10-22T12:00:00Z",1,
        "2020-11-24T12:00:00Z",1,
        "2020-12-17T12:00:00Z",1]},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}
```

Also, referring to some other QA, tried to build as below:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore/select?facet=true&facet.field=ds_clip_date&facet.range=ds_clip_date&f.ds_clip_date.facet.range.start=2020-12-15T00:00:00Z&f.ds_clip_date.facet.range.end=NOW&f.ds_clip_date.facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY
```

The result is as below:

```
{
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "ds_clip_date":[]},
    "facet_ranges":{
      "ds_clip_date":{
        "counts":[
          "2020-12-15T00:00:00Z",0,
          "2020-12-16T00:00:00Z",0,
          "2020-12-17T00:00:00Z",0],
        "gap":"+1DAY",
        "start":"2020-12-15T00:00:00Z",
        "end":"2020-12-18T00:00:00Z"}},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}}
```

However in the above summary you can find that 2020-12-15 has 20 documents indexed.

I am running SOLR 8.7.

Comment: Three `facet.query` entries that match the intervals you're looking for is probably the way to go. `facet.query=ds_clip_date:[NOW/MONTH TO *]&facet.query=ds_clip_date:[NOW-30DAYS/DAY TO *]&facet.query=ds_clip_date:[NOW-90DAYS/DAY TO *]&facet.query=ds_clip_date:[NOW/YEAR TO *]` - or you could create the intervals in your own controller before querying Solr.

Comment: @MatsLindh - Tried running the same and it provides as below:
{
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
}}

Comment: Oh, you have to include a query as well. Facets are calculated across the documents returned from the query. Add `q=*:*` if you want to facet across all documents in the index.

Comment: This in case returns all the set of indexed documents from Solr (dis-respecting the range). I am so sorry but @MatsLindh - are you able to help me drafting a query, probably adding your bits to the below:

http://localhost:8983/solr/testcore/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=ds_clip_date&facet.query=ds_clip_date:[NOW-30DAYS/DAY%20TO%20*]

Comment: Just to be sure - you actually want to generate _facets_, right? I.e. a _count_ of the number of documents matching your query? If you're looking to only filter the result set, use `q` with the query itself instead. Facets generate counts of documents containing a term or matching a query (like in this case), giving you counts for how many documents are in each bucket. The documents returned by the query is irrelevant to the counts (as long as they're included) - the counts in the buckets will match the query submitted.

Comment: @MatsLindh - I managed to get the required as below:
`fl=ss_title%2C%20ds_clip_date&fq=ds_clip_date%3A[NOW-2DAYS%20TO%20NOW]&q=*%3A*&&rows=200&start=0`

So, basically I wanted to do a search on range of days but at the end figured out without using facet.range option.